# TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/second Invalid filter: 'get_val'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

this is my function in views where I am separating comments and replies and changing reply into a dictionary

```
def blogpost(request,slug):

    variable=Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    comments=Comments.objects.filter(post=variable,parent=None)
    replys=Comments.objects.filter(post=variable).exclude(parent=None)
    replyDict={}
    for reply in replys:
        if reply.parent.sno not in replyDict.keys():
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno]=[reply]
        else:
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)
    return render(request,"blog/blogpost.html",{'blog':variable,'comments':comments,'user':request.user,"replys":replyDict})
```

here I am displaying my replies

```
 {% for reply in replys|get_val:comment.sno %}
            {{reply}}
            {% endfor %}
```

here i am parsing my dictionary to find a proper pair for the sno
from django import template

```
register=template.Library()

@register.filter(name='get_val')
def get_val(dict,key):
    return dict.get(key)
```

Comment: You are missing the `{% load %}` tag. For the example [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) it is `{% load poll_extras %}`.

Comment: thanks Alasdair it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def blogpost(request,slug):

    variable=Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    comments=Comments.objects.filter(post=variable,parent=None)
    replys=Comments.objects.filter(post=variable).exclude(parent=None)
    replyDict={}
    for reply in replys:
        if reply.parent.sno not in replyDict.keys():
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno]=[reply]
        else:
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)
    return render(request,"blog/blogpost.html",{'blog':variable,'comments':comments,'user':request.user,"replys":replyDict})
```